# How to pass data in a class to another member?

Tags: java, android, paypal, this

I have this code and I am trying to pass `this.thecost` to the `public void click()` method but it looks like it is not working because I receive "Paymnet Failed" when click the paypal button.

What did i go wrong?

by the way, what do you call the `private {}`, `private void {}` - all those function() looking thing?

```
private void initUI(int theprice) {

        launchPayPalButton = mPayPal.getCheckoutButton(this, 
                PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.bottomMargin = theprice;
        this.thecost = theprice;

        launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout2)).addView(launchPayPalButton);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        payWithPaypal(this.thecost);
    }


private void payWithPaypal(Integer gg) {
        PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(gg);
        newPayment.setSubtotal(bigDecimal);
        newPayment.setCurrencyType(Currency.getInstance(Locale.US));
        newPayment.setRecipient("email@hotmail.com");
        newPayment.setMerchantName("My Merchant");
        Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, this);
        this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(resultCode) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            String payKey = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
            data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Paymnet Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Paymnet Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Paymnet Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String errorID = 
            data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_ID);
            String errorMessage = 
                    data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            break;

        }
```

EDITED: I call initUI() at the oncreate method

EDITED AGAIN: I change the global variable to 'double' because the price usually have decimal place.
Now i tried to toast the value and i see the error much clearer. The toast display a message that the value that was passed is "0.0". And because of that, there is an error of 'Payment Failed' and invalid payment.

```
int eprice;
    double thecost;    
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);

    //Data mSource = new Data;
    Intent myLocalIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle myBundle = myLocalIntent.getExtras();



    eprice = myBundle.getInt("eprice");
    String epricetxt = myBundle.getString("eprice");

    Adapter mAdapter = new Adapter(this, mSource);
    //details = (Data) mAdapter.getItem(pos);





    TextView theprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.priceTxt);
    theprice.setText("Price: $" + epricetxt);





    this.setCost(eprice);
    this.thecost = eprice;



    //Paypal
    mPayPal=PayPal.initWithAppID(this,Constants.PAYPAL_APP_ID,PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

    initUI(eprice);

}

private void initUI(int theprice) {

        launchPayPalButton = mPayPal.getCheckoutButton(this, 
                PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.bottomMargin = theprice;
        this.thecost = theprice;
        launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout2)).addView(launchPayPalButton);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //
        payWithPaypal(getCost());
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.thecost = cost;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return this.thecost;
    }


    private void payWithPaypal(Double gg) {
        PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),gg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(gg);
        newPayment.setSubtotal(bigDecimal);
        newPayment.setCurrencyType(Currency.getInstance(Locale.US));
        newPayment.setRecipient("email@hotmail.com");
        newPayment.setMerchantName("My Merchant");
        Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, this);
        this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's failing because of the cost and not some other reason? What's in errorMessage?

Comment: Seems there's no issue with 'thecost' field. Have You checked 'errorID' and 'errorMessage' You're receiving in onActivityResult()?

Comment: hMM... i check but no error. But i am wondering why when i put
    public void onClick(View v) {
        payWithPaypal(10);
    }
It works. But when i put this.thecost, it did not work

Comment: @user2041851 Where are you calling initUI(int theprice) from? You need to make sure you call that method to set thecost to a valid int. I just updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my most updated code, I have no idea why my eprice doesn't work. But I have alternative solution. All i need to do is change

initUI(eprice);

initUI(Double.valueOf(epricetxt));

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough information to tell you what went wrong here. For some reason, the PayPal API returned a failure status code. Maybe you don't have an internet connection?

Check the value of the error message string that you retrieved in this line:

```
String errorMessage = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

You can use the debugger to inspect it, or use the Log.e function in the Logger class to log it to Logcat so you can read it.

As for your second question:

> by the way, what do you call the private {}, private void {} - all those function() looking thing?

In Java, those "function looking things" are called Methods.

EDIT: Okay, now that you've showed us your onCreate method, I can see where you are getting the value that you eventually pass to onInit here:

```
eprice = myBundle.getInt("eprice");
```

Doing this implies that you saved the value previously in the bundle in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`

Did you do that? How does it get the value when you are starting the Activity for the first time?

Comment: Hi i see the error much clearer now. the value being pass to the click method is '0.0'. And i m not sure what cause it

Comment: Okay, so you have to figure out where that came from. You're getting the value out of the bundle in onCreate, but it's not clear where that was put into the bundle. I edited my answer again with more info.

Comment: yup. I did that too. It is correct. TextView theprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.priceTxt);
    theprice.setText("Price: $" + epricetxt); this code shows that the value is correctly saved.
But I have alternative solution. All i need to do is change

initUI(eprice);

to

initUI(Double.valueOf(epricetxt)); and it works. hmm but still wondering why the other didnt work